# how to mock the deletion of a file? (linux)

Tags: linux

In order to run some tests, I need to run an app that will delete a file

Since it's expensive for me to recreate this file (>40 GBs) every time I need to run another test, I want to mock the deletion of this file.

But this must be completly transparent to the app deleting it. That means creating a symlink is not an ok solution ([ -L symlink ] returns 0 while [ -L file ] returns 1, so this wouldn't be completly transparent for the app).

Comment: anyone know about unionfs? seems it might help, but I never worked with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several solutions. `dd` like solution may take some time, however using *seek*

```
dd of=mybigfile bs=1 count=0 seek=40G
```

is instant. *however* the 40g space taken by the command is *not* seen in `df`...

So the best is probably

```
fallocate -l 40g mybigfile
```

that creates instantly *mybigfile* and the space is actually reserved from the FS (and is seen in `df`)

-- *edit after comment* --

What about a hard link

```
cd data 
make 40g file "myfile"
```

then for each test

```
cd ../test 
ln ../data/myfile testfile

command to unlink testfile
```

*data* and *test* dirs being on the same FS (different dirs to prevent mistakes etc..).

The hard link status is pretty transparent and is not likely to be tested by the application . The *unlink* operation will remove the name associated with the inode and then decrement the links counter in the inode, and should be very fast (the file and its data will be actually freed only when the inode counter goes down to zero - which will not happen unless you unlink also `data/myfile`).

Comment: I didn't know fallocate. Pretty cool. But unfortunatelly it doesn't solve my problem because the content of the file is important (there's a check before it's deleted)

Comment: Hard links seem like the ideal solution here.

Answer (score 3):

Use a filesystem that supports snapshots. ZFS and btrfs come to mind. Just take a snap with the file present, and then restore that snapshot after each test.

Both of these filesystems take snapshots in such a way that restoring should be very fast.

Comment: yes, I guess that works. Can you think on something that doesn't require a filesystem change? Maybe hooking the remove-file syscall with a kernel module or something?

Comment: Nope, can't think of anything else. Honestly, this would likely be much faster to implement than some kernel hack...

Answer (score 3):

For things like this, I prefer to use an `LD_PRELOAD` trick. Write a tiny C library that mocks `unlink` (and maybe `stat64` if the test also checks for file existence) and preload it. Test it on a less important file :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Create a hard link to the file to be deleted, like `ln original /some/where/safe`. Go ahead and blow away the file, it won't be gone (just the link, which you can recreate any time).